# Changing images with button click, array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

When I try to run a script which will change the lights when I press the button, nothing happens, the images don't even show. Any way I could fix?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>

<p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>

<img id="IMG" src=N:\Year 10\Computing\Exam\A452 Practical Exam\Interactive Buttons\>

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list=[];
    list[0] = '<img src="N:\Year 10\Computing\Exam\A452 Practical Exam\Interactive Buttons\red.jpg" width="254"height="501" alt="Traffic Light Red">';
    list[1] = '<img src="N:\Year 10\Computing\Exam\A452 Practical Exam\Interactive Buttons\green.jpg" width="249" height="494" alt="Traffic Light Yellow">';
    list[2] = '<img src="N:\Year 10\Computing\Exam\A452 Practical Exam\Interactive Buttons\yellow.jpg" width="243" height="506" alt="Traffic Light Green">';

function changeLights() {
  var list = document.getElementById('IMG');
    if list=0 {
    image.src='<img src="N:\Year 10\Computing\Exam\A452 Practical Exam\Interactive Buttons\red.jpg" width="254"height="501" alt="Traffic Light Red">';
} else if list=1 {
    image.src=1;
} else if list=2 {
    image.src=2;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you think "if list=0" is doing? How do you think this code is deciding which of these If statements to use?

Comment: put your script tags in the <head> of the document.

Comment: maybe because you are missing quotes around your `src` attribute.

Comment: I only get an error at line 21(if list=0) as @master565 said, I'm a student, and I'm new in this environment

Comment: @George - You're using invalid syntax for the if statement.  You need to use parenthesis.

Comment: @George, there are two things wrong with the statement if you haven't figured it out yet. First off, you access an array through a statement like this list[0]. list=0 means nothing to an array. Second, even if list=0 was a correct way to access an array, it wouldn't work here. If statements require a conditional case. list=0 is an assignment because you only used one = sign. Assignments like this will always return true. What you were probably looking for was list==0, which checks for equality. But once again, this is mostly irrelevant because you are accessing the array wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="IMG" src="N:\Year 10\Computing\Exam\A452 Practical Exam\Interactive Buttons"\>
```

brackets!

Change only src, not whole html object:
`document.getElementById("IMG").src="change.png";` - use relative path, its same folder as your html file. Don't use explorer path xD

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework!

Your understanding of how to access an array in Javascript is flawed.  Take a look at the following examples.

```
var list = [];

// Assign some values
list[0] = "Fred";
list[1] = "Wilma";
list[2] = "Barney";
list[3] = "Betty";

// Check the length of the array
alert(list.length);

// Iterate over the array outputting the values.
for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    alert(list[i]);

// Access values directly
var sentance = list[0] + " is married to " + list[1] + " and " + list[2] + " is married to " + list[3] + ".";

alert(sentance);
```

You're also going to need another variable to keep track of the index of the value you're displaying so you can increment to the next image.